# Telegram bot inline keyboard callback not working

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm using PHP for the telegram bot. Reply callback is working when the callback hit the callback URL but the inline keyboard callback not working. When I click on the inline keyboard button, nothing responds, why it's happening? Please help me to fix the issues.

````
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, true);
$userChatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"]?$update["message"]["chat"]["id"]:null;

if($userChatId){
    $userMessage = $update["message"]["text"]?$update["message"]["text"]:"Nothing";
    $firstName = $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"]?$update["message"]["from"]["first_name"]:"N/A";
    $lastName = $update["message"]["from"]["last_name"]?$update["message"]["from"]["last_name"]:"N/A";
    $fullName = $firstName." ".$lastName;
$callback_query = $update['callback_query'];
$callback_query_data = $callback_query['data'];


$url = "https://webhook.site/f695055e-5a65-4120-9ea2-0581667bbd61?kk=";
if(isset($callback_query)){
    file_get_contents($url.$callback_query_data);
}

if($userMessage == "/start"){


    $replyMsg = "Welcome to Bot";


    $keyboard = [
        'inline_keyboard' => [
            [
                ['text' => 'Button 1', 'callback_data' => '1'],['text' => 'Button 2', 'callback_data' => '2']
            ],
            [
                ['text' => 'Button 3', 'callback_data' => '3']
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $encodedKeyboard = json_encode($keyboard);

    $parameters = array(
        "chat_id" => $userChatId,
        "text" => $replyMsg,
        'reply_markup' => $encodedKeyboard
    );

    send("sendMessage", $parameters);
}
}
function send($method, $data){
    $BOT_TOKEN = "Telegram_key";
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$BOT_TOKEN/$method";

    if(!$curld = curl_init()){
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close($curld);
    return $output;
}

?> ```
````

Comment: Why are you not checking what response the API actually gave you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented something to respond the callback query?!

When you receive an update object, you can check `callback_query` field for a `CallbackQuery` object that has `data` field containing a string. Handle it as you handle the normal messages:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

> NOTE: After the user presses a callback button, Telegram clients will
> display a progress bar until you call answerCallbackQuery. It is,
> therefore, necessary to react by calling answerCallbackQuery even if
> no notification to the user is needed (e.g., without specifying any of
> the optional parameters).